# Image and Text overlapping

Tags: css, image

I have an anchor tag and i want to set the background of the anchor tag with an icon depending on the situation.

So i have the following classes:-

```
/* Folder Icons CSS */
.FolderOpen {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(../images/icon_folder_24x24.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.FolderClose {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(../images/icon_folder_24x24_closed.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The **image sizes** are **24x24**

I have my achor tag as following:-

```
<a class="showFilesForFolder FolderClose" data-folderid="@folder.FolderId" data-personid="@Model.PersonId" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;"> <span>@folder.FolderName</span></a><br />
```

The image is not displaying to the full height and width.

Can you please help me so that the text doenot overlaps the image and image displays nicely?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with padding (in this case, left), and the background image position,  to give space for the anchor text not to overlap.

**HTML**

```
<a class="showFilesForFolder FolderOpen"><span>Folder open</span></a>
<br />
<br />
<a class="showFilesForFolder FolderClose"><span>Folder close</span></a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    // The trick is here:
    padding-left: 30px;
}

/* Folder Icons CSS */
 .FolderOpen {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    // Position your background image
    background: url("http://www.thenetadvantage.co.uk/wp-content/themes/netadvantage/images/icon-linkedin.png") no-repeat top left;

}
.FolderClose {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    // Position your background image
    background: url("http://computer-forensics.sans.org/images/design/custom/icons/twitter-icon.png") no-repeat top left;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qg7Ns/2/

Answer (score 2):

you should use image tag inside your anchor tag. Then you can set css to get the right position of text and image.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a jsfiddle to see clearly?

Why dont you just float the text around an image?

Comment: Is this an answer? It should be a comment instead.

Comment: question was not to overlap text and image.  how is it not an answer?

Comment: The image is used as a background, so your comment makes no sense.

Comment: you are saying this is a bad answer.  You agree if it was not a background then it would be an answer, ergo its an answer that you go out of your way to call a comment?  The answer includes changing the structure from background to image.  Since there is no reason given for using background it could be that using images instead will solve all problems and give better performance, depending.  I dont get what your point is.

Comment: It's a bad answer regarding this question in specific. I'm not saying it's a bad solution. If there's a way (and there is) to answer to the question keeping the original idea, that's the way to do it, not to make the OP change the whole code, unless it's really crappy and invalid.

Comment: again the question was to not overlap.  How does a solution involving  changing the original idea make it a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Use padding and/or text-indent, fiddle the padding to fit your needs,

```
padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
```

Padding goes from top clockwise to left, so top, right and bottom padding in the example are set to 5 px, the left padding to 10.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `display: block` on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
.folderClose {
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
  background-image: url('../images/icon_folder_24x24_closed.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This works I hope.